# Covariance not working with delegates

Tags: c#, botframework

I am working on a project using `Microsoft Bot Builder`, but my question is not specific to that.

Microsoft Bot Builder has the following delegate

```
WaterfallStep(DialogContext dc, IDictionary<string, object> args = null, SkipStepFunction next = null);
```

And my method's signature is

```
async Task DidNotUnderstandQuery(DialogContext context, BotState state, SkipStepFunction next)
```

Notice the only difference is `BotState` parameter type which is defined as below

```
class BotState : Dictionary<string, object>, IDictionary<string, object>
```

When I try to substitute my method where it is supposed to be a `WaterFallStep` I get the error saying the method does not match the delegate.

Why does Covariance not work with delegates?

Comment: If your method had looked like `DidNotUnderstandQuery(DialogContext context, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>> state, SkipStepFunction next)`, it would have been fine by contravariance, since `ICollection<KeyValuePair<,>>` is a base interface of `IDictionary<,>`. But you have the "is a"-relation going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your method expects a BotState argument, but WaterfallStep expects IDictionary. Imagine that some other code attempted  to invoke the delegate with another dictionary, that would not be type safe since the method would think it is BotState. Covariance on input parameters is not allowed (only contravariance).